# Http 404 error no message file .jsp in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, http-status-code-404

I'm new playing JAVA EE programs and I have one problem.
Until today, I've run my program doing right click on the project (called 'test') and left click on Run on server. As I've said, until today my programe had run starting with the page 'inicio.jsp' but I don't know why, today the program starts with another page, called 'index.jsp.
I can't run the 'inicio.jsp' and if I go there through a link from index.jsp it appears the following error:

Estado HTTP 404-
type: Informe de estado
message:

### description: The resource is not avaliable

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56

I don't put pictures because I'm new in this community and I have no reputation enough to post images.

Thanks.

Comment: What file you configured in web.xml file under <welcome-file-list> tag. If you have Index.jsp then server starts index.jsp page